# 19 hour offset when setting moment to 0 (using moment.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

Solved my own problem. I wanted to convert seconds to HH:mm:ss using moment.js. I used the following code, which worked, but I didn't know why moment(0) was setting the time of day to 19 00

```
var yearZero = moment(0).subtract('hours',19); //beginning of time
var sTimecode = yearZero.add('seconds', secondsUntilEvent).format("HH:mm:ss");
```

From http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-offset/

```
moment(Number);
Similar to new Date(Number), you can create a moment by passing an integer value representing the number of milliseconds since the Unix Epoch (Jan 1 1970 12AM UTC).
```

Didn't see anything about starting at 7PM / 19 00 there

The problem was that I was outputting it without declaring UTC. The following change did the trick:

```
var sTimecode = moment(0).add('seconds', secondsUntilEvent).utc().format("HH:mm:ss");
```

Perhaps someone else encountered the same problem (or not). Good day!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing such a complicated workaround, you can always use the moment constructor to read an integer, which is interpreted as the number of milliseconds from the unix epoch. This works fine for me:

```js
var value = moment(18000 * 1000).format('HH:mm:ss'); // 5 Hours

document.getElementById('date').innerHTML = value;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>
<pre id="date"></pre>
```

Obviously, the time is displayed accordingly to your browser's timezone